# How to get database details from DSN in linux?

Tags: linux, zend-framework, dsn

I am digging around an linux webapps using zend framwork. I couldn't find database connection string except the following in the zend_config.xml

```
<webhost>domain.com</webhost>
<docroot>/var/www/vhosts/domain.com</docroot>
<database>
<CLW>
<dsn>mssql://xyz:xyz@sql02/domain_prod</dsn>
</CLW>
<banner>
<dsn>oci8://INTERFACE01:astr0s06@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL =  TCP)(HOST = bnrprod)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = prod)))
</dsn>
</banner>
</database>
```

How can I find the db connection string from this?

There is nothing found in /usr/local/etc/odbc.ini or  /usr/local/etc/odbcinst.ini.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your database parameters to application/application.ini or bootstrap. not a zend.config.